# Ban URL shortening services

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, blocklist

> ***Related***: [Ban LMGTFY links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) | [Shall we spam-flag lmgtfy-links?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64453/shall-we-spam-flag-lmgtfy-links) | *[URL Shorteners cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205806/url-shorteners-cleanup)*

Ban URL shorting services from being used in questions/answers. I have three major reasons to request this:

1. It's abused to hide LMGTFY-Links (interestingly, this behavior ranges from the 20 rep Newcomer to the 50K User)
2. It's used for inlined links, which negatively affects usability (I can't see where the link is taking me)
3. It's used instead of proper formatting

As requested by ChrisF, a few examples of misuse (all removed by now):

- [I need to convert my Mysql database to SQL Server 2005 database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2782661/i-need-to-convert-my-mysql-database-to-sql-server-2005-database/2782680#2782680)
- [Is Making a DLL compatible to all database is good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959161/is-making-a-dll-compatible-to-all-database-is-good-idea/959166#959166)
- [How to generate XML from an Excel VBA macro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2766760/how-to-generate-xml-from-an-excel-vba-macro/2782022#2782022)
- [Recommendation on big integer calculation library.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659528/recommendation-on-big-integer-calculation-library/3660364#3660364)
- [import email from gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633123/import-email-from-gmail/3633165#3633165)

**Update as of 19th Aug '13:** In the light of the recent [spam attacks on several SE sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192820/recent-mass-football-spam), Id' like to suggest to reconsider the stance on this.

Those spam attacks are mostly enabled by the fact that the spammers can hide behind shortened URLs (goo.gl in this case), making blacklisting of the original URL impossible. Banning at least the most well-known services would force spammers to use their original URL (or would block the attack as a whole), making it easier to directly target them.

Comment: What's your evidence for point 1?

Comment: @ChrisF I've seen it before as well.

Comment: @ChrisF: I've used up my 10 Mod-Flags on SO for this today, but hold on a sec, I'll get you some exmaples.

Comment: @George: [waffles' comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/15650/comments). Yeah, it's meta, but it's also a proof-of-concept.

Comment: related: [Shall we spam-flag lmgtfy-links? ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64453/shall-we-spam-flag-lmgtfy-links)

Comment: @George I was thinking of the 50K rep user - who should know better

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what 50K moderator used a URL shortener to hide a LMGTFY link?  I'm the only mod that I know of in that range and I'm reasonably sure I've never posted a LMGTFY link on SO (but I drink, so I guess it's *possible* that I posted one and forgot).

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: It was around 50K, 49 or 48 maybe. I wondered that myself, flagged it none the less and I can't find it right now anymore. Oh, sorry, I wasn't talking diamond here, just a normal user with that much reputation.

Comment: @Bobby: Whew!  I've been pretty outspoken against LMGTFY, so I was bracing myself for some embarrassment.  :)

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Sorry, I call everyone above 10k moderator, maybe I should stop doing that. ;)

Comment: Ok, what's stopping me from setting up a url shortener in one of dozens of domains? Or how do we even keep up with new services that pop up?

Comment: @NullUserException: Go ahead, as long as you use it for something useful. But at the moment if I do a search for 'tinyurl' everything that pops up falls under one of the three points I mentioned above.

Comment: A big thanks, btw, fir the flagged posts.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: You're welcome. I'm out of flags so more will come tomorrow. ;)

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby you linked back to this question in "Given the recent spam attacks" - is this intentional, or did you intend to link to some other post?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: This is intentional. The spammers hide behind URL Shorteners, making it impossible to blacklist them, unless we blacklist the shortener itself. ... And I was for banning them anyway, that's just another good reason to.

Comment: What is "LMGTFY"? Did you use some sort of sentence-shortening service? ;-)

Comment: @Spudley: [Wait, let me answer that with a simple link...](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=lmgtfy). ;) And now you know why we hate it...I hope.

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby - actually I did know the answer. I was just amused by the irony of using an acronym to describe a problem caused by shortening URLs. Hence the smily at the end of my comment. (that said, it's good that you've posted the link, as no everyone would know it)

Comment: long URL's dont fit in comments http://tinyurl.com/zaz9lha

Comment: @TonyStewart Comments should ***never*** contain important information, they are for clarification only. And if that is done, the question/answer should be edited to include that information.

Comment: Are monetized shortlinks like adf.ly also banned?

Comment: @Zackary As far as I know, [yes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105208/correct-procedure-for-dealing-with-adf-ly-links-shortening-service-that-pays-po). Having links like ad.fly has two problems: First, it is an URL shortener. Second, somebody is making money of content which they might not own.

Comment: By the way, the formatting on the actual error message is kinda broken as of 2018-03-03, there's HTML just sitting there.

Comment: @Stackstuck Please open another question for that complete with a screenshot if there isn't one.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

To me, this is the same as trying to ban curse words -- it's a fundamentally broken and bad idea.

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html

For every one we detect (even if we do an INSANELY EXPENSIVE HTTP REQUEST on every unknown URL, which is a completely and utterly ridiculous proposition) and block, others will pop up.

Better, saner, more sustainible to have a policy and use flagging to enforce it. Which incidentally is the [same way we approach actual curse words on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-allowed-in-comments)!

Thus, I am declining this as far as **automated enforcement of url shorteners** goes. It's untenable, period. But of course we encourage people to **flag hidden lmgtfy links** and we will follow up on those -- the policy is that lmgtfy isn't allowed, and that isn't changing.

Comment: Short-links are for Twitter, not SO.

Comment: I actually want to change my opinion, I like using short URLs, because that gives me access to see how many actually clicked the link.

Comment: @Emil It seems to have little use, as most people will click, see where link goes and immediately close. I will, at least. Although, more often I don't bother to even click.

Comment: It /may/ be a nice idea though, to, when you have the edit rights to do so, see a short link, expand it manually yourself and update the edit to reflect the link target.

Comment: Shortened links, are, well, short. It's quite good heuristic to skip matching against shortener blacklist if links are longer.

Comment: What? 99% of shortened links come from 10 services, and this is written from the dystopian future where link shortening companies and frameworks run wild as far as this post is concerned. It is *not* expensive to maintain.

Comment: Or Use flogging to enforce it?
Some links are painfully long, though.  What if you only allow shorteners that let you see the actual before clicking, e.g., http://preview.tinyurl.com/_____

Answer (score 37):

URL shorteners are at some risk of turning into broken links.  I'd say that we should have a policy to discourage use of url shorteners, and consider banning the major URL shorteners.

Since it's possible to get the terminating URL from the shortening service, it might be worthwhile instead to implement code to replace them with the final URL when the post is submitted.

This will also eliminate the problem of someone setting a shortened URL to a valid source, then switching it to spam or worse after the question has dropped off the front page.

Comment: You don't think Libya is a good top level domain? ;-)

Comment: @Arjan It's just fine if you ignore the current unrest there... http://www.centernetworks.com/libya-shuts-down-the-internet-domains

Comment: Even before the current events, `.ly` [revoked domain(s?)](http://blogs.forbes.com/davidewalt/2010/10/06/libya-revoking-ly-domains-that-dont-adhere-to-sharia-law/). But then: maybe it's more likely a service stops by itself. Many of us remember Tr.im I guess.

Comment: @Arjan Yep, while I was at first referencing the current tld `ly` issues, the reality is that such services really aren't guaranteed. If you start to wonder how they pay for their servers you may start to consider their longevity a bit more seriously. Since they are generally used for ephemeral communication (chat, twitter, etc) then they may not put a high priority on longevity, and I've even seen some services start to re-assign urls in order to keep the overall length short, expiring them after 90 days or so. I don't think they are a good fit for the repository Stack Overflow intends to be.

Comment: (When writing my first comment and its smiley above, I had not yet heard how unbelievable bad the situation in Libya has become today. Very, very sad.)

Comment: @Arjan Yeah.  It makes me feel petty, thinking that I *might* be inconvenienced if a paltry internet service goes down, compared to what they're dealing with.

Comment: "it might be worthwhile instead to implement code to replace them with the final URL when the post is submitted" @Pollyanna does your 500 Rep Bounty imply that you're asking someone to create code for such a job?

Comment: @The No, my bounty is meant to bring the issue up again and request that Jeff reconsider his stance.

Comment: @Pollyanna yeah after posting that comment, I went through and red a number of questions about Mate Bounties to learn the logic behind posting bounties on questions like this.

Comment: @The Oh, I use bounties for [many other things too...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42501/is-bounty-rep-dump-gaming-subtitle-pollyanna-lottery)

Comment: [So do other people, I have noticed with great delight](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49433/replace-trilogy-raw-links-with-the-current-question-title/49435#49435) :-)

Answer (score 24):

Despite my first impulse to down-vote this I must say I do in fact agree. There are certainly advantages of short URLs when you share them in a non-copy-pasteable way, e.g. via SMS or phone, but since this is not the case here, I'm all for it. Especially wrt 3.

Comment: Seriously, what's so hard about clicking that Hyperlink button if one doesn't know the `[linktext](http://ur.l "alt text")` syntax to produce a nice link?

Comment: Currently comments can only post 600 characters. And links are often ridiculously long, e.g. the link of this current page is over 90 characters. (Indeed many many links are over 100 characters long.) By *usability-right*, the system should not include url characters into the 600 character limit, A short URL is a good stopgap solution to this problem. It also serves as a good stopgap solution to the [url scheme problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64505/159916).

Comment: @Pacerier It would actually make a good [tag:feature-request] to not count URL characters. OTOH 600 characters is quite a lot and comments shouldn't become exhaustive on non-meta sites. And many URLs can be stripped of referral and meta stuff after the `?` and `&`s

Comment: [Indeed it has already been requested](http://goo.gl/ncY5Vk), but I wouldn't bet that it will get much traction.  600 char limit may be about right if it doesn't count URL chars. But if we include URL chars, comments with multiple links in them easily exceed 600 chars even though they may be *non-exhaustive*. And there are many cases whereby the meta stuff after `?` and `&` is required in a link...................................................................

Comment: ........e.g. when we want to link to the 45th second of a certain youtube video, or when we want to link to a certain *direction* in google maps. Also, in cases when these meta stuff is optional, not many people know how to hand edit URLs to safely remove them, e.g. changing [this link (401 chars)](http://goo.gl/R0kbe0) to its [shorter version of 364 chars](http://goo.gl/OPauXg). People simply copy whatever link they have in their url bar and paste that. If short URLs were banned, this very comment would need a few more posts to complete since there is 765 total chars in the unshortened links.

Answer (score 20):

Automated blocking or rewriting is probably never going to happen; [as Jeff notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64509), that gets quite expensive.

But there's some educational value in limited blocking of specific, popular shorteners. We've been trying this out on Stack Overflow for a few months now, and the results have generally been positive.

So I've blocked a few common shorteners network-wide (with the exception of this site):

- bit.ly
- ow.ly
- goo.gl
- tinyurl.com
- adf.ly

These are ONLY blocked in post bodies (unlike SO where they're blocked everywhere); I have no desire to handle a lot of complaints about this, since updating the rules on 300+ sites can be a bit error-prone. Let's hope the educational value is sufficient here.

Comment: If someone tries to edit a post that contains a shortened URL that was added before this change was made, will they be prompted to remove it before they can submit the edit?

Comment: Yes, they are prompted (I just tried it). Also, it seems the shortened urls are being banned not only in text and hyperlinks, but also in code blocks!  Why are they being banned in code?

Comment: I was just now able to bypass the ban using HTML entities, so the blacklist is effectively useless.

Answer (score 13):

While I agree with the sentiment (I hate the use url shortening services where length isn't relevant), I don't think banning them will do any good. There are dozens of such services, and keeping a ban list up to date will always be a hassle.

Instead I would just suggest we encourage all those with edit privileges to edit out the shortened URL and replace it with a full link.

Comment: Since short-URLs redirect anyway, they could be detected by a simple http-request when posting that link. And edit-monkeying for *this* stuff is really a bit of a nuisance...

Comment: Good point about the ban list, but Tobias's comment is pretty convincing.

Comment: @Tobias: There are any number of non-shortening-related and perfectly valid uses of an HTTP redirect that might be triggered by a link posted to SO, particularly if it's somebody typing from memory (e.g. lots of sites redirect `domainname.tld` to `www.domainname.tld` or vice-versa). Trying to automatically detect them needs an AI. Sadly, I don't have one in my pocket. :(

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: Wait, did you just call me a monkey because I'm editing my way through the search results? ;)

Comment: @Tobias: Interesting idea. The server could submit the http request and if a redirect occurs just replace the URL directly with the redirect result. @Nicholas: I don't think it matters that there are valid uses of redirect. The server would just auto replace the URL, this would be fine even if it was just resolving dn.tld to www.dn.tld. Of course the cost of the http request would need to be looked at. It could be done async out of the direct path, but it would still add to the server load. It probably depends on how many URLs are posted.

Comment: @Bobby: what? whoops, no!

Comment: @Simon, @Nicholas this could maybe turned into a different feature-request: "automatically replace redirecting links with their final destination (excluding SOFU's short permalinks)". Should of course have an infinite loop detection and refuse posting if more than 5 redirection jumps occur

Comment: @Tobias Kienzler: @Jeff Atwood had pointed out (as a comment on an answer which seems to have vanished) that this would take an expensive HTTP-Roundtrip which he isn't willing to spare (which I understand).

Answer (score 10):

As ArchiveTeam says, [URL shorteners are a ticking bomb in the WWW](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=URLTeam).

An answer or question linking an URL shortener has a way lower value than it would have if it contained the full URL. It's at risk of losing meaning at any moment and, consistently with the practice to discourage link-only answers because the link target might vary, such URLs should be discouraged.

Similarly, Wikimedia projects [already block URL shorteners on sight](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Spam_blacklist). Sure, some work for a while, but in the end they are blocked. SE already has a ban in place to force usage of "example.org" and friends in the examples, so why not do the same for URL shorteners?

Also, if you care about the issue, remember to help [301Works.org](https://archive.org/details/301works) and [URLTeam](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=URLTeam) (e.g. by adding more shorteners to the wiki page and by running an [ArchiveTeam Warrior](http://archiveteam.org/index.php?title=ArchiveTeam_Warrior)).

Finally, it's not 2010 any longer, and an [INSANELY EXPENSIVE HTTP REQUEST](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64509/248268) for every link could be performed by [Internet Archive's Archive-It service](https://archive-it.org/) with a minor contribution from StackExchange's budget to ensure that every link is preserved in the long term (or at least any link which survives the first line of defense against spamming for a day or two). Internet Archive preserves a billion web pages per week. :)

Answer (score 8):

I agree that it's impossible to maintain a canonical black-list of URL shortener services. Users *will* find a way around it, if they wish.

However... I suspect only 5-10% of the users who use short URLs do so in a malicious way. The majority simply think they are superior to normal links (for whatever reason) and might even be surprised to discover we don't like them on Stack Exchange.

Therefore, I see some merit in a scheme that blacklists the 30 top URL shortener sites. The goal is to catch the average user who innocently uses a `http://goo.gl/...` link and needs reminding that we don't like that.

The remainder, who may just have innocently used an obscure shortening service, can be handled with flagging and what-not. The actual persistent evaders can face some moderator justice.

Don't abandon this scheme simply because you can't achieve 100%. Aim for 90% and be happy with it!

Comment: The problem is that if goo.gl is banned, a significant number of people will use an alternative. And this is not good, because while goo.gl links may have near 99% certainty of future existence, the alternative links will have a (much) lower certainty of future existence, giving us broken links.

Answer (score 7):

URL shorteners can be used to link to schemas different from `http://` or `ftp://`; `irc://`, `mumble://`, `steam://`, `mms://` links come for example to mind.

Since I'm not looking forward to give links to these resources as plain text, I'm not looking forward to URL shorteners getting banned.

Some URL shortening services actually block minifying links to non http:// schemas; TinyURL doesn't.

Comment: Wouldn't the solution to this problem be to allow different (safe) URL schemes? And I'm not sure masking non-HTTP URLs with HTTP shorteners is outside the bounds the aforementioned abuse: the expectation is set that they'd be going to a web page, not that they're going to open their IRC client, FTP browser, or whatever else.

Comment: Very good point. There's even dedicated common URLs such as http://tinyurl.com/aboutconfig -- but for some reason my Firefox stopped honouring that redirect...

Comment: @Mark: the post context can very well change your expectation; e.g., "SO has chat room, [click here to join it](irc://irc.freenode.org/stackoverflow/)"; good luck whitelisting all "good" schemas.

Comment: @Mark http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken

Comment: So URL shorteners should be allowed as a workaround to a site policy? Either those protocols are unwanted, hence that's one more reason to ban URL shorteners; or they are wanted, hence they should be whitelisted. [Protocol whitelists](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUrlProtocols) exist, it's not *that* hard.

Comment: @nemo we do not have control on the protocol whitelist on this site.

Comment: @badp, true, SE is not free software. However, I'm not convinced that allowing a policy loophole is a good solution to having an unflexible policy. I prefer policies which make sense. :)

Answer (score 4):

You are a bit late with this, specifically tinyurl.com/so-hints has been used many times in the past couple of months or so.  The problem here is not the URL shorting service, it is the people that use them.  Ban their posts if they abuse it, ban the user for repeat offenses.  Don't ban the tool.

Comment: -1, every use of these tools here is an abuse. We're not on twitter; the character limit here is 30,000. As such, there are no benefits to using shorteners. There are cons, though; besides the obfuscation of LMGTFY, someone could obfuscate, say, a site running malicious scripts under a link reading "see the documentation here."

Comment: I'm all for banning tools. Users that are tools.

Comment: @Pops, There **are** benefits to shorteners, as demonstrated by http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services/64505#64505 and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services/64451#comment-786035

Answer (score 4):

Years later, this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). [At least on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/319465/6083675). No other sites have the ban, not even the localized SO sites (Japanese, Russian, Portuguese, Spanish).

The solution is not retroactive, so there are still many posts that have these link shorteners (but refuse your edits unless you remove them).

I have set out to remove them as described in [Removing link shorteners from posts!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321494/6083675)

From my experience there, I will tell you it was a good idea to block these links. Many of them have resulted in irreversible link rot, sometimes ruining the question/answer.

I would like to see a similar thing on other sites to prevent similar problems.

Answer (score 3):

I often use URL shortenening when it's impossible to use a regular link.

[Example][1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

This is especially true when it comes to comments, where we have to use the [link](url) syntax.

Example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science)

(notice the parenthesis)

Comment: @Peter See example

Comment: Works [just fine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_science%29) when you replace the last parenthesis in the URL with the escape sequence `%29`.

Comment: @NullUserException - I deleted my comment, since I found [the reason why URL shortening is useful in comments](http://bit.ly/a9rozy) <== I cannot include that URL w/o shortening.

Comment: @Popular So I should start memorizing html entity codes?

Comment: I'm aware that this is useful for comments, that's why I included mainly answers/questions in my request. Though, that problem with the wiki-link should be reported as bug, imho.

Comment: @null no, just use one of the other five different ways (other than bare cut and paste) to include URLs, which work fine with parens. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: And links that might work today, might not have worked [in the past](http://superuser.com/posts/30591/revisions). Likewise, how can we be sure no bug will ever keep one from posting a working link? In the rare cases that I did use a URL shortener, it was always because of some Markdown rendering issues.

Comment: As an aside: for an overview of different ways to add URLs that contain parentheses, and which of those are currently broken in the preview, see [Links to URLs containing parentheses](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses/13509#13509)

Comment: @Null, no, I'm not suggesting that. I haven't even memorized it myself, even though I've seen that trick documented multiple times before and I like that link syntax. It took me five tries to get it right so that I could write that comment. I wouldn't have mentioned it, except that you used the word "impossible" instead of "very annoying"; technically, it's not _impossible_, and I thought people should know.

Comment: @Pops Technically `%29` has nothing to do with HTML, it is URL escape sequence.  When copy-pasting addresses from Firefox location bar, the parentheses are already URL-encoded.  Do the literal parentheses pop up in any other case than manually typing the URL?

Comment: @Palec Good point about the terminology, I fixed it. Not sure what was going on regarding your second question; maybe things worked differently three years ago?

Comment: @Pops I don’t think so. IIRC the browsers only used to display the escape sequences in location bar those days. Now they display them decoded (while internally still using the encoded version). But I must admit a have just a little experience with browsers other than Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

I often post links in comments which point to a specific fragment in a specific document of a specific documentation. The URL may be quite long that way, which severely limits the amount of useful text I can include in my comment.

If you ban these things, then please also find a way to [make URLs in links not count towards the comment length limitation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137036/dont-make-urls-and-title-attributes-count-towards-comment-character-limits). Otherwise, don't.

A constructed but realistic example (taken from [this post of mine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/255835/188688)) would be the following comment, which is too long by 10 characters unless one uses a URL shortening service:

> You can use a [`SaxSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html) [constructed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/sax/SAXSource.html#SAXSource%28org.xml.sax.InputSource%29) from an [`InputSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?org/xml/sax/InputSource.html) if you want to [`transform`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html#transform%28javax.xml.transform.Source,%20javax.xml.transform.Result%29) a [SAX event stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML).

Comment: This means that the link address in `[]()` syntax should not count into the comment length. Because that is the keystone here.

Comment: @tohecz, Yea, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shortening-services/64451#comment-786035

Comment: @yo' is right. However, the ban could be restricted to answers and questions, which have no length limit and should be written for the long-term.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this like 5 times.

Answer (score 1):

**Please unban the goo.gl shortener**.   It's only valid for Google services, so it really can't be misused, and it's the *only* way to get shareable links to Google Maps, which is very useful over at Travel.SE, particularly for giving directions or sharing exact locations.

Comment: goo.gl appear to be shut down, so it's pointless to unban it. There are still tons of "bad" links.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not open to random users, but Google services like Maps still generate goo.gl links when sharing.  Here's one from Maps generated right now: https://goo.gl/maps/2GdZmA9tPrR2

Comment: So perhaps make it a per site thing, e.g. no need for this on sites other than Travel.

Comment: @jpatokal You can still get and use the long link, though.