# Shall we spam-flag lmgtfy-links?

Tags: support, flags, spam, lmgtfy

Since it's [banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links), do those who circumvent it by short-URLs deserve a spam-flag?

Comment: related: [Ban URL shorting services](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services)

Comment: I've been flagging them for 'Moderator Attention' since some weeks.

Comment: @Bobby, I'd upvote that as an answer.

Comment: @Popular Demand: Aarobot beat me to it. Thanks none the less.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No.  They aren't spam.  Downvote them and/or flag for moderator attention explaining what they are; a mod can delete them and take any further action that may be necessary in case of repeated abuse.

Edit: The above assumes that the link is an *answer*.  If it's a *comment*, you obviously can't downvote and there are no distinct flag reasons, so just flag it.  One of the reasons for flagging a comment is "noise" and lmgtfy comments are definitely noise.

Comment: I wouldn't even downvote them. If you flag them they'll get removed anyway.