# chrome:// link does not show up as a link

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, hyperlinks, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links with URIs of schemes other than http/https are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken)

I would like to link to chrome://net-internals/ (a local Google Chrome page for debugging purposes), but it won't let me do that:

1. When I click the link button, it results in `chrome://net-internals/` (notice the `http://` prepended to the actual URL).
2. When just pasted, it doesn't show up as a link: `chrome://net-internals/`

I understand that there are hardly any links of this type, but since this format (`foo://bar/`) is clearly a link, could such links be parsed as actual links?

Comment: Right. This is a security feature of Google Chrome, and many other browsers. And I have no idea what this has to do with the Stack Overflow website. Are you trying to link to this page from one of your *Stack Overflow answers*? If so, there's no need. Just use the inline code formatting option to display the link text.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I thought Markdown was not parsing it. If it's due to Google Chrome, then I'll forget about it. From my point of view a link would be more user-friendly, but I'll leave it as text.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I misunderstood. Yeah, Markdown is probably appending an `http://` and the link probably isn't clickable. But even if that was fixed, I don't think Chrome will let you click links to these pages anyway. It's a logical security feature to me: keep the web separate from the non-web. I don't think it poses a significant detriment to answer quality if you have to include this as text, rather than a link. People can figure out to type it in the address bar.

Comment: @Cody Gray: You're completely correct. I removed the `http://` manually on this page, and although the link was still there, it wasn't clickable.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Links that point to targets that don't have schemes matching `https?|ftp` are removed as part of the post-Markdown HTML sanitizing process, so as this is very much intentional I don't see it being changed.

If it were allowed Chrome would keep the link as-is, though for the security reasons that Cody Gray mentioned it would be pointless anyway, as clicking the link would just generate a security exception.