# Add link to windows 8 store app

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Links with URIs of schemes other than http/https are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken)

I can't add link to windows store app, since MS is using the ms-windows-store: protocol. For example this link works in browser, it opens the Windows store with our application.

```
ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=WebMarketing.Coolinarika_tp6yaakah33yj
```

But if I put it as a link, Stack Overflow is complaining that

```
http://ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=WebMarketing.Coolinarika_tp6yaakah33yj
```

is not a valid link. Note the http added in front. If I try it with

```
ms-windows-store://PDP?PFN=WebMarketing.Coolinarika_tp6yaakah33yj
```

it still is not recognized as a link by the SO engine.

Comment: Why would you need to put such a link here?

Comment: AFAIK, the Windows 8 Store is accessible from Windows 8 and up only. Allowing these knds of links would give broken ones to those of us who don't have it. Hardly a universal protocol. Itunes apps have a web-based preview page, does the W8 store not have something similar?

Comment: I've reproed with plain text, `<>`, `[]()` and `[][]` formatting, so it's not just you. However, like Robert, I don't know why you would need to actually create a link, instead of just stating "my app links to `ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=WebMarket...`."

Comment: I was trying to answer a question how to put direct link to windows store, and yes it has web preview, don't understand why downvote ?

Comment: here is the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236111/linking-to-apps-in-windows-store

Comment: Ah, I see from your profile that you don't spend much time on Meta. Welcome! Downvotes here often indicate disagreement, not problems with your post. I'm _guessing_ that the downvoters think it's good that `ms-windows-store:` is not supported, and disagree with your assessment that it is a bug.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarification, when I think about it I agree now with downvoters, it's really not a bug :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because it's not a valid link anywhere except in Windows 8.

This doesn't seem worth fixing - we don't support every possible link protocol out there and I don't think your example really *needs* to be a link either. You're showing the link format for the OP and that seems sufficient.