# Ban/mark/decorate external links requiring paid membership or even "free registration"

Tags: feature-request, discussion

This for example:

[SQL Replace ASCII With Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990964/sql-replace-ascii-with-loop/4991552#4991552)

There is a link in that comment to http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

I was looking forward to reading up on some good technique, and the pop-over the page was truly obnoxious.  I am fundamentally against requiring capturing of my details (even if bogus) just to read some article.

I guess the sentiments will be same as Jeff's here

[Ban URL shortening services](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services)

> To me, this is the same as trying to ban curse words -- it's a fundamentally broken and bad idea.

But this is easier right? There are only so many "free registration" sites that are easily identifiable.  Maybe we can decorate them with tags next to them like "registration required" or "membership" or some such.

Comment: -1 vote reason: I agree with Robert Harvey's answer.

Comment: Let me introduce you to [BugMeNot](http://bugmenot.com/).

Comment: @Helen Not all sites work with BMN. Some actively disable logins found there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Do you really want to put up another blacklist?

If you feel strongly about it, I think an appropriate response would be a comment on the answer to the effect of:

> Thank you for this answer, but it is
>   behind a registration page, and I find
>   that really obnoxious.

There is nothing the OP can do about that, of course.

Users are generally encouraged to put a summary in their answer describing what the link content is about, since it helps with link rot, and reduces the problem of registration pages since the link may no longer need to be followed.  You can also mention this in a comment.

I have a throwaway Yahoo email account that I use to register these kinds of pages so I can read their content.  Kinda like a giant bit bucket.  Interestingly, the messages I get in there (although I seldom read them) have a much higher signal-to-noise ratio than my spam folder.

Answer (score 2):

Just vote such posts down if you don't like them. And say why.

I'm with you on the matter, but this should be a matter of grass roots activism, not policy.