# How to deal with spammy content in otherwise legitimate answers?

Tags: discussion, spam

There is a [particular user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/758715/user758715) who has just started what appears to be an advertising campaign for a specific user group/community/whatever.

This user's modus operandi seems to involve appending a standard "Join this group for more amazing tricks" to all of his/her answers. I have removed a couple of those, but I am starting to think that a more concrete response may be necessary...

I suppose that bringing this up in Meta will probably attract the right kind of attention, but, for future reference, what should one do in such cases? Should they:

- flag as spam, even if the answer contains otherwise relevant and potentially useful information?
- flag for moderator attention?
- edit the spammy content out and leave a comment?
- just edit the spammy content out and go on with their day?

PS: It should be noted that this user has made no contribution to SO since registering over a year ago, until this spam campaign started a few hours ago...

Comment: A [somewhat similar question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/140393/when-is-it-appropriate-to-link-to-your-own-paywalled-website-from-your-answers) generated a lot of interest last week. Not exactly the same situation, but some of the same principles apply.

Comment: FYI, it seems they have all been cleaned up now. And the user [seems ready to leave](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638682/shell-script-to-set-the-gnome-terminal-title-and-run-some-commands-on-gnome-term#comment15417325_11638682). (Though not as a result of the cleanup it seems)

Comment: @PopularDemand: That was an interesting read, although it seems that this case is more clear-cut; removing the links changed nothing in the amount of information conveyed by the answers, which IMHO is a clear indication of spam...

Comment: @Bart Wow. Oded was polite, informative and patient (as usual) and the guy's still quitting? I guess some people just interpret anything other than "here r t3h codez" as a grievous insult.

Comment: @PopularDemand: I don't think this user is/was here to ask and answer questions...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's just one or two posts you can edit it out and go about your day knowing you've earned our gratitude.  There's also a relevant section of the FAQ you can link to in your edit message. [Can I use a signature or tagline?](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

If it looks like the user is persistently using a tagline on the majority of their posts, you can flag for a moderator and we'll private message them (as I did in this case).

Comment: Well all the links are gone now and hopefully this user will not persist. Thanks for your answer and for the assistance...