# Is this user advertising his product acceptable?

Tags: discussion, spam, advertising, self-promotion

I noticed quite a number of posts where someone would advertise an alternative serialization library, since I more or less follow the [boost-serialization](/questions/tagged/boost-serialization) tag.

Just now, I got another one: [Packing struct in Boost Asio buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868875/packing-struct-in-boost-asio-buffer/22871124#22871124), and decided to have a look.

To my surpise, this user https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639596/wood-brian has almost exclusively self-promoting answers.

- The vast majority of his 39 answers mention and link to his library<sup>**[1]**</sup>.
- Most often, it starts out with a link, and
- Not infrequently the answer has a tenuous link to the question, and sometimes, the answer doesn't contain anything more than just the link

I do realize this is at least in part a work of love. I do personally feel it's a bit too much, though, and it might have crossed the invisible line where it becomes abuse of StackOverflow for advertising purposes.

- In particular, I feel that all three "checks" offered in Andrew Barber's answer "[Is it allowed to put links to personal technical blogs having advertising in SO answers or comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141589/is-it-allowed-to-put-links-to-personal-technical-blogs-having-advertising-in-so/141591#141591)" have been neglected
- The statistics in **[this much heavily-debated case](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/140413/159703)** were far less outrageous (Brian has a 90% advertising pay load rate, way higher than this "spammer"'s mere 16%!)
- There's jurisprudence in the [Ira Baxter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/120163/ira-baxter) case (episodes 1..n, see "[Limits for self-promotion in answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57497/limits-for-self-promotion-in-answers)")

I don't know whether the guy has any commercial interest in spreading his library, but aside from that, the principle should be considered: when is spam spam, and when is it somehow acceptable? Or, when do we allow advertising, even though we prohibit it in general?

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> In fact, it's easier to link the few answers that are **not** advertising his product:

- [Best container for C++ class objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973903/c-best-container-for-class-objects/16974630#16974630)
- [C++: fastest to write vector file to output in normal text mode (not binary) in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857331/c-fastest-to-write-vector-file-to-output-in-normal-text-mode-not-binary-in/15858852#15858852)
- [IPC message queues how to send a vector of pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963653/ipc-message-queues-how-to-send-a-vector-of-pairs/13964795#13964795)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445172/how-to-boostserialize-an-exception/13445874#13445874 (on the bright side, he's [maintaining](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13445874/revisions) his answers). **NOTE** This one links to his site, but doesn't directly advertise his product as the solution, so I don't count it in my list of "offenses"(?)

---

[Here's a collage of the 18 most recent answers in case they get clobbered/are inaccessible to <10k users.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4RzO.jpg)

**Update** November 10th 2014 added a chapter to this story. In a now-deleted meta.SO question (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276430/a-stubborn-self-promotor-has-returned ) I exposed a list of newly added answers by the same poster. In the interest of historical reference, here is a screenshot of that question after @animuson handled it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mB9y1.png

Comment: PS. I omit the site/product name here in the interest of not inadvertantly helping [SEO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization). Just click any link to find it

Comment: faq entry: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94022/147247

Comment: @KateGregory thanks for that. I do feel that's more on the topic of "shallow answers" than that of "advertising" (though it's obviously related, in that it concerns using SO to drive traffic to external resources)

Comment: Added a collage of the 18 most recent answers in case they get clobbered/are inaccessible to <10k users: [Imgur-ed collage http://i.imgur.com/JEeoBrC.png](http://i.imgur.com/JEeoBrC.png)

Comment: You fooled me! You claimed that link was a *collage*, but it's merely a *scroll*! :p

Comment: I'm doing what the subject of your profile picture is right now :0

Comment: I've mod flagged a user for this before and something like 40 of their 100 answers were quickly disposed of.

Comment: Looks like spam to me. I flagged one answer with a link to this post. But if this is allowed, more will follow.

Comment: FYI: the same user also added several comments with a link to his site.

Comment: There's no pricing on the linked site, but the registration is required and it seems the usage of the library is dependent on their servers. It's very untransparent and looks suspicious.

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ I didn't think it was a licensed product. But it sure looks like at least the person is looking to create consultancy jobs off this for himself

Comment: @sehe I haven't seen the info it's free, and if it is, why isn't it just available for download? Anyway, you don't post answers suggesting using of the whole product when OP wants one simple thing... Well, maybe with exception of jQuery, but jQuery is free and < 300kb :P

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Oh, maybe one would, but most often people already state they're using e.g. [tag:boost-serialization]

Comment: Problem is solved.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe Oh. What was the solution? I thought we were still defining the problem, even deciding whether it was one ([meta-tag:discussion]). I haven't noticed any authoritative response/clear consensus myself

Comment: The posts are deleted. So I assume the mods agree it was spam.

Comment: Oh well. That's fine I guess. I for one, specifically came to Meta instead of flagging as spam, but you're right, if enough people agree (enough being >0 mods, I guess) it was spammy enough.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: Okay, the mods may have agreed with that position, but the community hasn't yet. The answer you've now posted, though, seems to deal with this development much more clearly. :)

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer so we can see if the community agrees ;-).

Comment: @ToonKrijthe I noticed, you already have my +1 for that

Comment: @animuson in response to your deletion (thanks for explaining the reasoning in the comment), I have updated this post. I think it's good that we can track the history of what has been reported, and deleting that question makes it hard to see that something happened this day.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

While promoting your open source library on Stack Overflow is perfectly fine, I felt this user was a few steps over the self-promotion line.

- The vast majority of posts were linking to their own work.
- A lot of those posts contained little information other than the link.
- There was no disclosure of their affiliation.
- They really weren't helping the SO community in any other (non-promotional) way.

This all combined gives me the feeling that the user was here exclusively to promote their own work. I deleted their promotional posts and sent them a warning. If they can edit the more helpful posts (particularly the ones with code examples) to include a disclosure of affiliation, those posts could be undeleted.

Comment: Thanks for putting this reference point out there. Seems a reasonable course of action to me.

Answer (score 9):

I think this is spam and it shouldn't be allowed.

I flagged one post with a link to this meta post, and as a result, 37 posts of the user are deleted, so I assume at least one mod thinks it is spam too and as such not acceptable.