# Spammish reasonable answers

Tags: discussion, spam

I've noticed a lot of spam-like legitimate answers today.

See examples: 
https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/146009/928
https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/145850/928

This answer has all the hallmarks of spam.  User with 1 (or 101) rep, direct link to a product, and unusual verbosity.  It reminds me of blog spam.

However, it is a valid answer to the question.  What should we do?

Edit: Another example

Comment: My quick look says the answer is legit. Some questions simply attract product recommendations.

Comment: The other contributions of that user look OK so I wouldn't spam flag.

Comment: This is a new user who has 3 answers and a question and only one link to an external site. Seems legit.

Comment: The second user  has the same issue.  One good question, and one fishy answer.   It looks like rep farming in the way blog spammers used to try to manipulate the page rank algorithm.  I really don't know what's going on, and it has the look of legitimacy, with a fishy smell.

Comment: If it answers the question (like a "real answer") and spam promotes their product...to me that's...another answer, as it were...if the product answers the question...

Answer (score 4):

None of what you link to qualifies as spam. Those are legit attempts at answering a question and the userprofiles show other genuine looking contributions as well,

You can't use spam flags to get those answers removed, if that was your intent.

Use your votes if you think the answers are not useful.

If you have reason to believe a specific site is being promoted you can ask in [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq). They have a collection of [SPAM posts](https://metasmoke.erwaysoftware.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&body=www.cpelectronics.co.uk) and domains and can quickly asses if a site is being spammed in posts across the network.

Answer (score 2):

There's no bright line dividing "spam" from "not spam", which can be frustrating. [One explanation of relevant considerations that I really like](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228658/) comes from Bill the Lizard, describing a situation he moderated on SO:

> - The vast majority of posts were linking to their own work.
> - A lot of those posts contained little information other than the link.
> - There was no disclosure of their affiliation.
> - They really weren't helping the SO community in any other (non-promotional) way.

My own $0.02: spam is like lying. Just like there's a difference between "making a false statement" and "intending to deceive via falsehood", there's a difference between simply posting about an outside service/product and doing so because of some promotional or other ulterior motive.

If a user isn't obviously intentionally trying to take advantage of a site, I'd prefer to warn them and explain what the perceived problem is than assume bad faith/spam.

In your specific cases, I'd lean towards benefit of the doubt, for the reasons above and because I didn't find evidence of plagiarism.