# Should URL shortners be banned?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ban URL shorting services](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services)

There was a proposal over at [Security.SE](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/162/should-we-ban-the-use-of-url-shorteners-on-this-site) that URL shorteners be banned. I think this proposal should go for all of the SE sites. Except for in comments(and usually it's not needed there because there is a lot of room in them even), the use of URL shortening is completely pointless and only adds a level of indirection which puts readers at risk of malicious attacks.

So my proposal: When parsing links on new posts such as http://example.com check the domain against a list of common URL shortening domains. Examples include: bit.ly, tinyurl.com, tinyurl.cc, goo.gl, etc. and when they try to use such a url, bring up an error explaining for them to not use URL shorteners and to instead use a direct link.