# Do we need to resolve/block bit.ly and other URL shorteners to block lmgtfy?

Tags: feature-request, comments, lmgtfy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ban URL shorting services](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64450/ban-url-shorting-services)

Apparently this link (and probably others) are now being used to get around the lmgtfy.com block ([recent example, if you hurry before it's flagged away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11639956/how-to-delete-a-row-from-changetable-in-sql-server)):

http://bit.ly/PFJh0g

So my question is pretty simple: do we need to add something to prevent the use of these services to mask the true destination? Can we just block bit.ly, tinyurl.com etc., at least in comments?

Comment: At least in comments? Block them in answers. You get 30,000 characters to write your answer; there's absolutely **no** reason to use a URL shortener, **ever**. I can see it in comments since you're severely limited to what you can say and a long URL can destroy your character count.

Comment: @animuson you can always use multiple comments. Not everything has to be summarized in a single comment, if a URL happens to put you over the edge. The reason I said *at least* in comments, is that this kind of response is much, much, much more likely to appear in comments.