# Make the links in the "suggested edits" view clickable

Tags: feature-request, support, review, hyperlinks

It would be nice if links in the "suggested edits" view were clickable. This would allow to [check the new links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209839/178179) more efficiently. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can. Switch to the rendered output view for the edit (options directly above the post). The link is then clickable.

We default users to the Markdown view when links have been edited in a suggestion to make it more obvious that a link was edited and prevent users from secretly including spam in their edits. Links are never clickable in the Markdown view because Markdown is by definition the *unrendered* version of the text. It wouldn't make any sense to render them there.

Answer (score 5):

Another tip that could help if you are using Chrome is if you highlight the text and right-click there's an option to go to that link:

[image]