# Improving error message when blocking posts due to URL shorteners

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

Using [TinyURL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyURL) URLs in posts [is banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/289658/178179) on SE. The error message is:

> Body cannot contain "https://tinyurl.com/xai"
>
> Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links. 
> **Editors**: please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!
> For details, see meta.

[image: Screenshot of error message when tinyURL is inserted in post]

It'd be clearer to say:

> Body cannot contain "https://tinyurl.com"

instead of, in this case, "https://tinyurl.com/xai".

Answer (score 8):

Such a message would be incorrect ([proof](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71116811/4751173)). I don't know the exact regex that's blocking that sort of content, but the second paragraph tells me exactly what I need to do, so I'm in favor of keeping the message as it is.

Comment: Thanks, good point, in that case, just write down the entire URL in the error message then?