# How can I add a clickable magnet link to a post?

Tags: support, hyperlinks

How can I add a clickable magnet link to a post?

---

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
[data](magnet:?xt=urn:btih:5f96d43576e3d386c9ba65b883210a393b68210e&tr=https%3A%2F%2Facademictorrents.com%2Fannounce.php&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.coppersurfer.tk%3A6969&tr=udp%3A%2F%2Ftracker.opentrackr.org%3A1337%2Fannounce)
```

but the text isn't clickable (example: data).

I also unsuccessfully tried:

```
[data](https://tinyurl.com/xai-grok-1-llm)
```

but tinyurl shortlinks are [banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/398714/178179) on the main sites.

Comment: It's a deliberate choice to not allow such links: [Links with URIs of schemes other than http/https are broken](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71108/links-with-uris-of-schemes-other-than-http-https-are-broken)