# Bounty custom message text box allows too many characters

Tags: bug, bounties, character-limit

The custom message text box for bounties permits as many as 3,000 characters to be entered.  I think this is too many; this should be no more than about 1000 characters.  Can someone look into this?

[image: Bounty custom message box allowing 3,000 characters]

Comment: Somewhat related: [Line breaks/paragraphs for bounty text](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124016/line-breaks-paragraphs-for-bounty-text) (I don't think it's too many characters.)

Comment: `+1` 3000 characters is equivalent to five comments.

Comment: Gah, for some reason I clicked the screenshot to close the "popup". Twice.

Comment: Is this a real problem or are you just looking for things to complain about? Can you explain, even briefly, why this needs to be changed?

Comment: I'm feeling that this could lead to abuse--3000 characters in this context can be disruptive.  Isn't this the point of character limits?

Comment: @DragonLord: Bounties cost the OP minimum 50 rep, would this really be an outlet for abuse? Have you actually seen anything like this that resembles abuse? The problem doesn't exist, in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't see a problem with that. Abuse can be taken care of when it happens.

Even more, the count includes the non-visible characters in links to references, `[which](http://can.need/quite/a/few/characters "and some more for a title")` in a few cases.

Comment: That's a good point, but 3000 is still huge. On a side note: It always bothered me that Markdown syntax (especially for links) counts towards character limits (both maxima and minima).

Comment: I agree, Dennis, but [Formatting should not count towards the character limit on comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/formatting-should-not-count-towards-the-character-limit-on-comments) has been declined. Maybe one would reconsider thinking about links. Those were mentioned in that feature request, [but only in a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/formatting-should-not-count-towards-the-character-limit-on-comments#comment379797_52979).

Comment: Well, the feature request somehow missed the point. Not counting asterisks isn't really worth the effort...

Comment: Then what's the point of character limits if as many as 3,000 characters are allowed in a box where most don't enter more than about 100-150?  For this purpose, 600 characters is plenty.

Comment: Indeed, @DragonLord, *most* people don't enter a lot of characters. (Your previous comment was 185 by the way...) But surely *a few* like more than 600, as in comments I sometimes also need to shorten (readable) links to fit 3 or 4 descriptive references into a 600 character comment. Is it a problem? I haven't seen any example of that. A bug? I'd say: not at all. (365 characters without any links.)

Comment: @Arjan: [I tried.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137036/dont-make-urls-and-title-attributes-count-towards-comment-character-limits "Don't make URLs and title attributes count towards comment character limits") Not popular.