# Long bounty descriptions

Tags: feature-request, bounties, bounty-remarks

> This is not a duplicate of [Reduce Character Limit for Bounty Custom Text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/reduce-character-limit-for-bounty-custom-text). Here's why:
>
> I'm suggesting a 150-char limit, not a 600-char one.

I hate seeing long bounty descriptions like this one:

[image]
[List of first n prime numbers most efficiently and in shortest code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6309/list-of-first-n-prime-numbers-most-efficiently-and-in-shortest-code)

Generally, this is a language documentation in a bounty. Can we impose a limit on the size of bounty descriptions, please? I think the image speaks by itself, but, if you can't see it, here is the whole bounty remark:

> Perform this in Wentelx87. [github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87](https://github.com/CrazyPython/wentelx87). Here is a short description of Wentel. A little birdie told me I should bounty an existing question instead of making a new one. So here goes. > Wentel consists of, at the basic level, a memory pointer and an instruction pointer. Instructions are stored loaded into memory. The execution pointer moves to the right after executing the instruction at that memory pointer. > The program is loaded into rightmost slot of memory. For example, if your program is `0010 0000 0101 0100`, then the virtual machine will look like this when started: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0010 0000 0101 0100 (memory) ^ (execution pointer) ^ (memory pointer) (from [README][1]) --- --- Wentel documentation examples, thorough and clear explanation [here][2]. Wentel is language that is very hard to program in. Unlike brain**k, functions and GOTOs can be implemented. It emulates real machine code/assembly much better than brainf**k. Wentel is a simple language. 1. instructions are held in the rightmost cells, one cell = one instruction 2. execution pointer starts out on first instruction 3. execution pointer moves right 4. **the same cells that hold memory hold instructions.** 5. these are the opcodes:  **`0000`** - no-op  **`0001`** - if the current address's value is equal to the value stored by the adress defined by the next word, move the execution pointer to the address pointed to the next word after the word after the current address.  **`0010`** - move memory pointer to address specified by next word.  **`0011`** - deposit the current address of the execution pointer into the current memory address  **`0100`** - increment current memory address  **`0101`** - decrement current memory address **`0110`** - move memory pointer left  **`0111`** - move memory pointer right 6. and here are the specialized opcodes for output.  **`1000`** - output `0`  **`1001`** - output `1`

Started at: 2016-10-10 22:06:73Z
Author: [Agent CrazyPython](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41088) (41088)
Reason: Canonical answer required
Reputation: 150

Comment: Where's the request, it's hidden! I think the screenshot is sufficiently explanatory

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Can we impose a limit on the size of bounty descriptions, please?*

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος I think this is a good idea. Bounties with comments that long should just be asked as new questions. The length should be limited to the length of comments, or less.

Comment: @SomePerson Yeah, and I don't think you need to reply to me in this case, just put a comment right now :) Also, I think 150 characters is more than enough.