# Attitude shift over time in unmarked duplicates

Tags: discussion, voting, duplicate-questions

What is a realistic timeframe to reach consensus or review a topic?

Does marking duplicates hinder fresh perspective on certain topics?

For example, there's a 32-point difference on the topic of bounty text length:

- On Jun 20, 2012: **-1** [Bounty custom message text box allows too many characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136948/bounty-custom-message-text-box-allows-too-many-characters)
- On Apr 22, 2013: **+31** [Reduce Character Limit for Bounty Custom Text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177501/reduce-character-limit-for-bounty-custom-text)

Had this question been marked as a duplicate, would the community have expressed such strong upvote per the original question?

Comment: It probably wouldn't have. Meta is sometimes a very arbitrary voting machine. However, seeing as community consensus is neither a hindrance nor a guarantee that something will be actually implemented, I'd say it isn't a big problem that this occasionally happens.

Comment: @Pekka웃 That's a long-winded "6-8 weeks."

Comment: Its also because the way the argument has been put forward in both the questions. The older one just says "I think its too many"; whereas the newer one gives compelling arguments to favor the change.

Comment: And of course the OP of the latter made a funny with his bounty message. Don't know about the time distribution of the votes, but I wouldn't be surprised if it helped.

Comment: @Bart: It did help... Before the bounty was started on that question, it had about 9 or 10 net-upvotes..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite both questions being tagged [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), I am pretty confident that the difference in votes in the second question is mostly due to:

1. The arguments given
2. The humour used in the bounty and the edit

Also, there have been discussions on [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s with hundreds of upvotes yet, which still haven't been [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). Recently resparked: [discussion on disabling the language filter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/178400/183189). Follow the chain of related questions and you will see what I mean.

Conversely, there have been topics which were generally not received well, but have the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) tag: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed?page=436&sort=votes&pagesize=15.

All this to say, up/downvotes probably do not matter too much when it comes to decisions about what gets implemented. It also goes to show that some discussions can drag on forever, spanning multiple questions, while others are concluded on a very short notice. So concerning your first question:

> What is a realistic timeframe to reach consensus or review a topic?

About [6 to 8 weeks!](http://cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php)

Comment: You [totally dropped the ball](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178442/attitude-shift-over-time-in-unmarked-duplicates#comment538262_178442) at the end.

Comment: To prevent such ball-dropping from happening again, please use the calculator used by SE internally as well: http://cznp.com/6to8weeks/index.php

Comment: @Bart Don't worry, I'll get the hang of it in about 6 to 8 weeks.