Goo.gl links will stop working on August 25, 2025, which will break them in posts
Google's link shortener "goo.gl" was disabled back in 2018, but existing links still redirect to their destination.
However, according to this Google blog, on August 25, 2025, these links will stop functioning. Doing a quick search finds 9,042 posts that use goo.gl links.
Should we begin replacing those links with their destination?

Make sure to check that no posts exceed the character limits for posts as a result.

@Sonic with 30k characters limit, it's really really rare that a link will make it too long. This really shouldn't be a concern.

In addition, if needed, they can be replaced by another shortened URL from a different service.

Well in such a scale, we just can't do it ourselves, need something like what SE made for Jon Skeet 10 years ago. Good luck to us.

Looks like around half of them are on Stack Overflow specifically... it also looks like that number might be slightly inflated; it seems to include some amount of false positives like https://maps.app.goo.gl and https://photos.app.goo.gl.

@testing-for-ya I believe the limit on comments length is a "soft limit", i.e. the actual size of the field in the database is larger and comments can technically be longer, so if SE will just replace the links in the database level, there won't be any problem, and if people would ask "how come this comment exceeds the limit" we can explain this.

@zcoop98: It seems to me that those “false positives” can be avoided with a  search for url:"//goo.gl/" – still 7,647 results.

Some related post on per-site-metas: goo.gl is closing down (Mathoverflow Meta) and goo.gl links will be broken in a month (Pets Meta).

Related: a feature request that could mitigate similar problems in comments: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52976/formatting-and-hyperlinks-should-not-count-towards-the-character-limit-on-commen
